# Select distinct not working on MS ACCESS *.mdb database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a really old database (created in 2002) where I need to select the unique values and copy them to another  table.. unfortunately the select distinct is not working on the field.
There comes always the error that the field is too small to add the data.
[image]

As I have seen is there a restriction to the length of the fields. The column is set to long text. Do you have something like a workaround / solution how to solve it fast?
I have also tried to change the database to accdb from mdb without success.. still the same error.
Each field has 318 characters. I have like 5000 rows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried till now? Show your sql code! BTW: i'd suggest to read this: ["The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add" error when running a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-running-query)

Answer (score 0):

> The column is set to long text.

This is well known issue...

This should help: [MS Access: "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add" error when running a query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/error-running-query)

For further details, please see: [The Memo data type is now called “Long Text”](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-memo-data-type-is-now-called-long-text-dffe5e34-953e-4451-a05e-fba5d9b564b5)